# Process received apple push notification in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, xamarin

Is there a way to show or list Apple push notifications on any user page?

It's pretty hard to find where is the alert message is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Xamarin doc for Remote Notifications: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/remote_notifications_in_ios/.

Answer (score 1):

iOS handles the push notification for you, your app is only informed of a push notification if you app is running in the foreground or when the user clicks on the notification and you app is opened.

With the iOS SDK there is no way to get a list of notifications for you app, the best way to create this is by keep a list server side.

Have a look at [`MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification Method`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification)

Comment: oh i see, lots of buddy give some codes but i guess they were kidding with me darn it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235837/process-captured-apple-push-notification/21235895?noredirect=1#comment32114249_21235895 check this, i dont understand obj c but he says its possible :( anyway thanks for helpp, can u email me? haluky@live.com regrads

Comment: Well he saying that if you app is running in the foreground it is possible to detect an incoming push notification. But not to get a list of notification for your app. As he is saying `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:` will be called for any notification that are received when you app is in the foreground.

Comment: is there sample code monotouch ? i never saw anyone share it sadly

Comment: Sorry I'm an Objective-C developer, have never touched MonoTouch. But the docs are very clear and map very well to the Apple Documentation.